# how to make some dates disable in android.widget.CalendarView?

Tags: android, calendarview

I am using android.widget.CalendarView and I want to strict user not to pick date from some specified dates.
How to do that?

I have also attached a snapshot so you have a better idea, What I want to do,

[image]

Here I just want to disable dates from 22 to 24 so that user can't select these dates,

Comment: If you specifically want that these specified dates show up differently (e.g., grayed out) and do not respond to click events, I suspect that you would need to fork the widget and create your own that offers this capability.

Comment: I'have updated my question, nd I want to use the default CalendarView,

Comment: If `CalendarView` does not offer this feature, you will either need to fork it, use a third-party library, or create your own from scratch. AFAIK `CalendarView` does not offer this feature. You are certainly welcome to have some other validation in your UI that prevents the user from proceeding if the user chooses a "disabled" date.